# given $E(v)=(av^3)(L/(v-u))$, Determine the value of v that minimizes E.

Tags: calculus

a, L, and u are constants.

Seems to be an optimization problem but it's one unlike any that we've been shown how to deal with.

Comment: What kind of problems are you used to dealing with?

Comment: More intuitive geometry type problems. Maximize area/volume/surface area. The sort. Usually given at least one real constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I properly understood, you have $$E(v)=\frac{a v^3 L}{v-u}$$ Since you want an extremum value, compute the derivative and after minor simplifications get $$E'(v)=\frac{a L v^2 (2 v-3 u)}{(u-v)^2}$$ This derivative cancels at $v=0$ and $v=\frac{3u}{2}$ and for this last value, $$E\Big(\frac{3u}{2} \Big)=\frac{27}{4} a L u^2$$ Now, you must show that this corresponds to a minimum; so, use the second derivative test; you have, again after minor simplifications,  $$E''(v)=2 a L \left(\frac{u^3}{(v-u)^3}+1\right)$$ and then $$E''\Big(\frac{3u}{2} \Big)=18 a L$$ which is positive and so, you face a minimum.

For sure $v=0$ could also be considered, leading to $E(0)=0$